# Accessible navigation of large information trees

Tags: css, user-interface, tree, usability, hierarchical-data

I am developing a public website which is the front end to information about medical conditions.

After the user does a search (questionnaire based) they are presented with the results which are categorised in to sections and sub-sections.

Information items can be assigned to both sections and sub-sections.

At the moment sections are represented by tabs across the top and the screen and sub-sections by links in a sidebar. The links in the sidebar change depending on which section is selected.

The problem is the section names are quite long (several words) and as a result the combined length of the tabs is too wide for a standard screen resolution (1024 x 768). Therefore they wrap and break the page layout. We will also have to add additional tabs in the future.

With this problem in mind and the fact our target audience is quite wide, this is a public medical website, what options are there for presenting this kind of information in a way which is accessible and easy to navigate for an average user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long are the subsection names? Will *they* fit in the space for tabs? You’re likely to get better user performance if you put the section links on the side bar menu and the subsection links in the tabs, rather than the other way around. See http://www.usability.gov/pubs/040106news.html.

The other alternative is to put everything on the side bar menu. Subsection links can appear indented under their section links. You can also consider putting the subsection links in a column of their own to the right of the section column. This makes the section menu stable, but takes a lot of horizontal space that’s perhaps better used for content. In either case, proper attention to visual design will show the current section, subsection, and the link between them.

There shouldn’t be a problem with accessibility as long as you’re using links to navigate to each section/subsection (perhaps generated programmatically for each page based on a database relating links to pages).

Comment: Very good point about swapping the positioning of the tabs and sidebar links, not thought of that, but unfortunately they are also multi-word links of a similar length.

I think what you are suggesting could be combined with an accordion: http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/ 

Clicking a section shows the sub-sections.

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming some ideas:

- Use combo boxes to allow the user to select the (sub)sections, then display the appropriate information items.
- Create separate pages for each section-level and provide a bread-crumb control to show the user where he / she is in the page hierarchy.
- Create some sort of fold-out menus that automatically hide when the user reads an information item.

In another question on SO, I came across a link to [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/), perhaps you can find some inspiration there as well.

Comment: I can't put my finger on it but I don't think combo boxes work here, they are perhaps a bit too far in the other direction. Instead of showing all page link (sections/sub-sections) they are hiding them all. Something in between maybe...

Bread crumbs would definitely be an option.

Quince is a nice way of presenting UI patterns. I shall have a proper investigate to see if anything jumps out at me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- An iPod-style menu (in which subsections are hidden pages that fly in from the right): http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

Or as Daan has said:

- Cascading drop-down boxes: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

The downside with both of these (over a traditional tree view) is that the subsections aren't visible until you choose a section. If your users don't know the name of the subsection they're after, then either of these will be a good fit.

If, on the other hand, they do know the name of the subsection they're after, it's probably better to give them an auto-complete textbox so they can type a few characters and go directly to it.

Comment: I've come across the ipod menu before, it is real nice. I think its a little too clever for our users, and again suffers from the combo problem of hiding too much information. And we have to support IE6 (Grrrrr).